# Adding an input field to the dom and focusing it in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, prototypejs

I am trying to make a div, that when you click it turns into an input box, and focuses it. I am using prototype to achieve this. This works in both Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. IE refuses to focus the newly added input field, even if I set a 1 second timeout.

Basically the code works like this:

```
var viewElement = new Element("div").update("text");
var editElement = new Element("input", {"type":"text"});
root.update(viewElement);

// pseudo shortcut for the sake of information:
viewElementOnClick = function(event) {
    root.update(editElement);
    editElement.focus();
}
```

The above example is a shortened version of the actual code, the actual code works fine except the focus bit in IE.

Are there limitations on the focus function in IE? Do I need to place the input in a form?

Comment: What is root and what does root.update do?

Comment: root.update replaces the content of the element with new content. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that IE hasn't updated the DOM yet when you make the call to focus().  Sometimes browsers will wait until a script has finished executing before updating the DOM.

I would try doing the update, then doing

```
setTimeout("setFocus", 0);

function setFocus()
{
    editElement.focus();
}
```

Your other option would be to have both items present in the DOM at all times and just swap the style.display on them depending on what you need hidden/shown at a given time.

Comment: I thought I had already tried this, but your answer seems correct. I need to wait 500ms though for it to actually work. I think I will just go with always have and input element rather than a div.

Answer (score 0):

What version IE? What's your DocType set to? is it strict, standards or quirks mode? Any javascript errors appearing (check the status bar bottom left for a little yellow warning sign) ? Enable error announcing for all errors via Tools > Options > Advanced.

Oisin

Comment: IE 7.0.5730.13 - I get no errors. using editElement.select() seems to focus the box, but it doesn't show the edit caret.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered by [17 of 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102055/adding-an-input-field-to-the-dom-and-focusing-it-in-ie#102152). I just want to point out, that Prototype has native mechanism for this: **[Function.defer()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/defer)**