# jQuery.replaceWith() on input field and regaining focus in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

There is a script

http://gist.github.com/457324

that sets default text (taken from element's title attribute) for empty `input[type=text]` and `input[type=password]` elements.

For password elements it is not that trivial though. If I did `$(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('title'));` for `input[type=password]` it would just show dots instead of default text. Changing type of the element (from password to text in this case) is not widely supported either. So the only way is to replace `input[type='password']` with `input[type='text']` element (util.js:26). This replacement seems to reset page tab index in IE and start from the beginning of the page. Other browsers behave as expected.

I found solution to similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102055/adding-an-input-field-to-the-dom-and-focusing-it-in-ie) but it does not work for me.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to write a function to do exactly this today and found your post. This function handles password field swapping by using a setTimeout() with a delay of 1 so the next "frame" of execution can focus on the element. Just call watermark() from a document.ready() context.

```
/** Support outerHTML in all browsers, from http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/jquery-outerhtml-snippet */
$.fn.outerHTML = function() {
        var doc = this[0] ? this[0].ownerDocument : document;
        return $('<div>', doc).append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};


/** Lightweight way to have subtle title instructions in text fields. */
function watermark(exclude) {
        if (!exclude) exclude = '';

        $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').each(function(){
                var self = this;
                function setTitle() {
                        if (self === document.activeElement) return;    // Don't change the currently focused field
                        if (self.value.length == 0 && !$(self).is(exclude)) {
                                $(self).addClass('textLabel');
                                if ($(self).attr('type') == 'password') {
                                        var newSelf = $($(self).outerHTML().replace(/type=["]?password["]?/i, 'type="text"')).get(0);
                                        $(self).replaceWith(newSelf);
                                        self = newSelf;
                                        $(self).data('restorePassword', true).focus(focus).blur(blur);
                                }
                                self.value = $(self).attr('title');
                        }
                }
                setTitle();

                function focus(){
                        if(self.value == $(self).attr('title')) {
                                $(self).removeClass('textLabel');
                                if ($(self).data('restorePassword')) {
                                        $(self).removeData('restorePassword');
                                        var newSelf = $($(self).outerHTML().replace(/type=["]?text["]?/i, 'type="password"')).get(0);
                                        $(self).replaceWith(newSelf);
                                        self = newSelf;
                                        setTimeout(function() {$(self).focus().focus(focus).blur(blur);}, 1);
                                }
                                self.value = '';
                        }
                }
                function blur(){
                        setTitle();
                }

                $(self).focus(focus).blur(blur);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks sunetos.
I have fixed it and the code is available as jquery plugin if you want to use it. http://github.com/misza222/Defaultize-jQuery-plugin