# Focus works in all browsers except IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, internet-explorer-6

Hey, just a quick question, I was using the focus function on elements and it seemed to be working fine because it was working in IE7, IE8 and all of the good browsers. When I tried it in IE6...nothing. It is a very basic line.

```
element.focus();
```

**VERY** basic. So does IE6 have a bug or problem with this function? I know the element object exists, I have tested for all of that and it works in all other browsers.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about IE6, it is far too outdated.

Comment: I know but it still has a percentage in the whole browser use pie chart. This is for a library so it is important that is as cross browser as possible. So does IE have a bug, does it just not work?

Comment: @Alexander. In my field, IE6 is a very prominent browser due to slow upgrade cycles. We can't always choose our target audience.

Comment: @Alexander: agreed. Supporting it means extending its expiration date. Let it die already ...

Comment: @Wolfy. What type of element are you trying to focus?

Comment: But I will be using this script for a council briefing system, the council run very old pc's. Most into the < windows xp era...*shudder*

Comment: @Jordan On an input[type='text']

Comment: Anyone who is still using ie6 honestly can't care about the internet, so if they can't see a webpage properly, it is their fault, and they should upgrade their browser.

Comment: I know this but I cant influence what OS and browser the council use. I have to take older browsers into account.

Comment: ie6 supports `.focus()` just fine (on elements that are focus-able) - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html you are focusing on an input. hence it should work and has always worked for me in ie6. do you get an exception or just that it fails to focus? how do you arrive to the element (selector, byid, event etc)?

Comment: Yep, that is all fine because it works in all of the other browsers. It does not throw any kind of error. It just does not give focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating the `<input>` element dynamically? [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102055/adding-an-input-field-to-the-dom-and-focusing-it-in-ie) might already have the answer.

## Update

Running Windows XP SP3 with IE6, I wasn't able to duplicate the issue you describe with the following file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function body_load() {
  document.getElementById("field2").focus(); }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="body_load();">
<input type="text" id="field1"/>
<input type="text" id="field2"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It always put focus on `field2` as expected. The following file works as expected too:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="field1"/>
<input type="text" id="field2"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("field2").focus();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are you using `application/javascript` as the `type` for your `<script>`? I know IE6 has issues with that. Perhaps posting an example that can duplicate the issue will help determine why it's not working.

Comment: Nope, it is there from the start.

Comment: Well if you download my library and run `spark.html` the second input on the page should be given focus. This should be a good test, if it works for you there too then it is my browser. The library can be found here: https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark

Comment: @Wolfy. It works for me, but only the first time I visit the page. If I refresh (F5), it doesn't refocus. If I click the Go button to re-request the page, it works.

Comment: Very strange. Seems like this could be an inconclusive question. I suppose it isn't a big deal. Focusing on an element is no major factor to any web app. Those few IE6 users will just have to click a couple more times.

Comment: You got the closest and helped the most, although it still does not work for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old but the same thing happened to me recently.

this works for me.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    element.focus();
}, 10);
```

hope it will be helpful to anyone who has to suffer with ie6:

Comment: You deserve a medal.